# Is the review audit too strict?

Tags: discussion

I just failed this audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6389342

Which while not an indepth answer it could have solved the problem (if correct) which should make it an acceptable answer.

The user could not add a comment and it was a configuration issue (just a different file that needed to be edited).

There anything to do in this case or do I just have to wait a few days to be able to review again?

Comment: What do you mean "wait a few days"? Are you review-banned? If so, this must not be your first failed audit.

Comment: I would tend to agree, that appears to be an answer. Unfortunately, you can't challenge the audit currently. I'm guessing it *is* an audit because someone flagged it and it ended up deleted, so its positive "signal" from the systems point of view.

Comment: @Bradley, the answer looks a lot like a jab in the dark, though, so the question is: do one-line jabs in the dark qualify as useful answers?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Useful, no. But its still an attempt at answering the question. It should have been downvoted, not deleted under the guidelines as I'm aware of them.

Comment: @Bradley, downvoting it would indeed have passed the audit. As for deleting it, I don't think we should apply the NAA strategy here -- valid attempts at answering can be deleted if they're weak enough.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah, forgot it was "First Posts" not "Low Quality", sorry about that. I still don't understand the deletion guidelines for VLQ. It has seemed to me that the consistent guidance is "If it looks like an answer", keep it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET [Why and how are some answers deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) suggests that "commentary on the question or other answers", "exact duplicates of other answers", or "not even a partial answer to the actual question" are candidate for deletion. The 20k ["Deleting answers" guideline](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) is "The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement".  I would contend that the post in question meets the low quality, commentary, or not even a partial answer criteria for deletion.

Comment: @MichaelT this discussion covers it quite well as well though, the quick and dirty answer can be very useful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758

Comment: @John why should the answer be quick at all when it was posted over a year after the question was asked.  The Fastest Gun In The West is not an issue here when the user could have spent an additional to write twice as much material.  One *could* argue FGITW when the post is within minutes of the question being asked - not when it's a year later.

Comment: @MichaelT because it could help someone in the future. It might have been a fix that that user found when they had a similar problem and wanted to share that for others. They don't have enough rep to post it as a comment and if it helps one other person then its worth it.

Comment: @John that is an issue of should it have been deleted.  *Not* a question of if you did the right thing for the audit or the first post review queue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is pretty much the same deal as [this case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278075/failed-an-audit-am-i-wrong/278085#278085).

One user flagged that answer as "very low quality" and another user flagged it as "not an answer". In review, a [unanimous vote of six users](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6311716) caused it to be deleted and validated those flags. I really do think that community-validated flags like this should not be used to generate audit cases, because this seems to be getting more frequent.

I'll lift your ban, as I did for the other user, but you do have some other questionable reviews in your history, so just be a little more careful with those in the future.

Reviews like this are also why I asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers).

Comment: Well, and it lead to a rename from "Looks Good" to "Looks Ok". Maybe it should be tempered some more to "No Action Needed".

Comment: Thanks for lifting my ban Brad. I tend to give people the benefit of the doubt and so say more things are "Ok" rather than try to close / delete as many posts as possible which has caused me to have this problem in the past. I don't know how to view my own failed ones so couldn't post any others for discussion. I know that even a quick guess at the problem has helped me in the past so don't want to have those deleted. Sounds like thats what you found in the your linked question as well.

Comment: I profit of this answer to ask if it's normal to be temporary banned for just 1 audit review failed? Not that it hurted me, just to know.

Comment: @Veve - No, you typically have to have a history of failing audits for the system to ban you. Some audits are more severe than others (failing a gibberish suggested edit audit should lead to a ban faster than others). Moderators can also ban you for individual reviews, if they showed extreme carelessness, but usually we only step in for cases of clear repeated abuse of the review system.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explaination. Maybe you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6383580 ? It's the only one audit (at my knowledge at least) I failed. I admit I didn't knew if the answer was correct but it didn't seems that bad to me.

Comment: But how to be more carefully? If not info is provided?

Comment: @Veve you could have commented about providing more information.  You could have tried to edit it so that it's a grammatically correct sentence.  You could have down voted it as not useful.  No action in a first post review queue cheats the first post of possibly valuable feedback about how to ask, the location of the help center and similar guidance that first posters often need.

Comment: @MichaelT : I failed the audit, there is no doubt about that. I was just asking if it was normal to have been temporally banned for only one failed audit. The ban ended anyway ;)